# Dependency Property inner Binding in custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'm trying to bind the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl contained in my UserControl (a group of radiobuttons) to a property of the same UserControl. This should be driven by the DependencyProperty when the UserControl is used. But I am not able to make it work, if instead I hardcode the control name the assignment works correctly.

This is the class :

```
public partial class GroupListBox : UserControl
{
    public GroupListBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<RadioButton> _itemsList = new List<RadioButton>();
    public List<RadioButton> ItemsList
    {
        get { return _itemsList; }
        set
        {
            _itemsList = value;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(GroupListBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnItemsSourceChanged));

    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (GroupListBox)d;
        var grpName = control.GetHashCode().ToString(); // used to generate a unique GroupName
        var oldValue = (IEnumerable)e.OldValue;
        var newValue = (IEnumerable)e.NewValue;

        if ((e.NewValue == null) && !BindingOperations.IsDataBound(d, ItemsSourceProperty))
        {
            control.ItemsList.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            var radioItems = (from object item in newValue select new RadioButton() { Content = item, GroupName = grpName }).ToList();
            //control.container.ItemsSource = radioItems; // *** this works
            control.ItemsList = radioItems; // *** this doesn`t
        }
    }
```

this is the XAML

```
<Border x:Name="brdMain">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtTitle" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="" />
        <Image x:Name="imgImage" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroll" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  CanContentScroll="True">
            <!--This is the control I want to bind-->
            <ItemsControl x:Name="container"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsList}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

used like this:

```
<cust:GroupListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SymmetryAxis}"></cust:GroupListBox>
```

I'm sure there is something wrong with my control binding but I don`t know what.
Any clue?

EDIT :
I did some little change in the XAML :
now it looks like this :

```
<ItemsControl Name="container" Width="{Binding ElementName=scroll, Path=ViewportWidth}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:GroupListBox}}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemPanelDatatemplate}" />
```

and this is the DataTemplate :

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ItemsPanelTemplate}" x:Key="ItemPanelDatatemplate">
    <RadioButton Content="{Binding}" GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Path=Name}"></RadioButton>    </DataTemplate>
```

This anyway gives problems with the GroupName because it`s always empty and then all the RadioButtons act like if they are in a single group.

How can I obtain the same result like in the code behind (for example assigning a unique name for each group?

Comment: Sounds like a really wrong approach to me. Why are you not using a simple `ItemsControl` and a `DataTemplate` instead?

Comment: Set your DataContext to whatever owns SymmetryAxis.

Comment: either in the ctor of `GroupListBox()` set `DataContext = this;` or set your `ItemsSource Binding` such as `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:GroupListBox}}}"` with `local` in xaml referring to the namespace that the `UserControl` is defined to. You could also just go with just `x:Type UserControl`, that level of type-safety is upto you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply : @HighCore - this is just the first iteration I want to make the binding works then I do it the right way. @Nick :  the DataContext for the SymmetryAxis works perfectly in fact when I receive correctly the newValue, the problem is to bind it to the control. @Viv : thanks for your help, setting DataContext doesn`t work, I already tried before to post this. But the second solution works but halfway : I see the labels of the Radiobuttons but not the Radiobuttons, I have no idea why

Comment: Yes, according to Snoop the WrapPanel gets filled with TextBlock instead of RadioButtons

Comment: Ok found why. Because SymmetryAxis is a List<string> which is what I want. I need to Bind ItemsList that is a List<RadioButton> so basically I want that given my labels the OnItemSourceChange generates the RadioButtons for that